# XMLHttpRequest doesn't get responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax, console, xmlhttprequest

I am doing the following from chrome console: (Could it be the reason for my problem?)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log("response:",this.responseText);
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://loc.gov/pictures/search/?q=a&fo=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
```

The url is valid and works cross-domain. Why does the `xhr.responseText` remains empty?

Comment: If it works cross-domain, then why are you using the `callback` query? Try this instead: http://loc.gov/pictures/search/?q=a&fo=json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted URL does not have CORS headers, but it does support JSONP.

JSONP on the other hand is not ajax, jQuery just neatly wraps it as such, but in plain javascript you have to use a script tag to get JSONP data

```
function JSON_CALLBACK(data) { // define callback function
    console.log(data);
}

// then create and insert the script tag, once loaded the callback will be called

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://loc.gov/pictures/search/?q=a&fo=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pVJ3L/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It does work. Try with this snippet:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://loc.gov/pictures/search/?q=a&fo=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK",false);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

The problem was that you were applying the function to the first change. It actually should be applied only to the four state-change event of the XMLHttpRequest object

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provided [does not work cross-domain](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/d34rv/). The server does not allow cross-origin request.

[image]

The version I used is the JSON one which returns a JSON. The link you provided is JSONP, which is not AJAX and you will have to use `<script>` to load it.

By the way, you are missing `xhr.send()` in your code and your xhr is never sent.